# New Picklist Values not showing in Flow Builder

Tags: visual-workflow, picklist

Trying to set up a Flow using Flow Builder but it isn't pulling through the latest picklist for Task>Subject (any task subject added today via Setup isn't showing). I'm able to use the new picklist values when adding tasks to Salesforce so it's not a picklist error. Any advice on what I should check would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is to wait a few hours for Salesforce to update everywhere.